# How to customize JSession ID

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

We are using JBoss 4.2. We would like to customize the session id which is generated by JBoss.
We should know from which server that particular session id is created in a multipath env. We would like to use first digit to identify the server.

For example:
JSessionID created by JBoss is 123456

Customized sessionid Should be:  A123456   (A-First server, B-Second Server, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set jvmRoute attribute in your engine config to jvmRoute="node1" for example.
This will end up generating a
JSESSIONID value that looks like
"ABCDEF123456.node1".